# Discord.py Embed Kick, Having a hard time turning this embed

Tags: python

I wanna turn this embed , I tried 3 times but cant get it. Can someone help by just sending me the embed version.
Thanks,
Code:

````
@bot.command(description="kicks a user with specific reason (only admins)") #kick
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def kick (ctx, member:discord.User=None, reason =None):
 try:
    if (reason == None):
        await ctx.channel.send("You  have to specify a reason!")
        return
    if (member == ctx.message.author or member == None):
        await ctx.channel.send("""You cannot kick yourself!""") 

    message = f"You have been kicked from {ctx.guild.name} for {reason}"
    await member.send(message)
    await ctx.guild.kick(member, reason=reason)
    print(member)
    print(reason)
    await ctx.channel.send(f"{member} is kicked!")
 except:
    await ctx.send(f"Error kicking user {member} (cannot kick owner or bot)")```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `discord.Embed` for making embeds.

Replace

```
    message = f"You have been kicked from {ctx.guild.name} for {reason}"
    await member.send(message)
```

with

```
    embed = discord.Embed(
        title="Kicked!",
        description=f"You have been kicked from {ctx.guild.name} for {reason}!",
        color=discord.Color.blue()
    )
    await member.send(embed=embed)
```

If you want the `await ctx.channel.send(f"{member} is kicked!")` part to be an embed too:

```
    embed2 = discord.Embed(
        title=f"{member} is kicked!",
        color=discord.Color.blue()
    )
    await ctx.channel.send(embed=embed)
```

You can use similar code for the error message.